# Laravel - No reply address is registered for the application in Socialite Azure AD Login

Tags: laravel, azure-active-directory, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel-5.8 for User Azure AD Authentication. I installed this package:

```
"socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure": "^3.0",

composer require socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure
```

I also did the configuration. The regular Login from database is working perfecting, but I have issues with the Laravel microsoft-azure integration.

**Login Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::with('azure')->user();
}
```

**login.blade**

```html
    <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class=" w3l-form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <div class="group">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
            <div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block" style="color: red">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class=" w3l-form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <div class="group">
                <i class="fas fa-unlock"></i>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a href="{{ route('azure.login') }}" class="btn btn-primary"> Azure Login</a>
    </form>
```

**route/web.php**

```
Route::get('login/azure', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('azure.login');
Route::get('login/azure/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

config/services

```
'azure' => [
'client_id' => env('AZURE_KEY'),
'client_secret' => env('AZURE_SECRET'),
'redirect' => env('AZURE_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

**.env**

```
AZURE_KEY= something
AZURE_SECRET= something
AZURE_REDIRECT_URI= http://localhost:8888/login/microsoft/callback
```

**config/app**

```
\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
```

When I clicked on Azure Login button, I got this error in the screenshot:

[image: azure login error]

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

New Error:

[image: object not found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add reply address for the application.

Go to Azure portal->App registrations->find your application->Authentication->add the Redirect URI.

[image]

Comment: When I did as you advised, I have another error: Object not found. I have updated my post with the diagram.

Comment: @mikefolu You should change the redirect url to a valid url.

Comment: How do you mean?  Kindly explain. Thanks

Comment: @mikefolu Change the AZURE_REDIRECT_URI to your website url, and on azure portal.

Comment: The application is on my local machine as http://localhost:8888/salesportal/    is that what you mean? Kindly assist me with an example

Comment: @mikefolu Yes, try with this. Use a url which you want the user to see after sign in

Comment: This is the url I want user to see after sign in. http://localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard   Am I still going to add /microsoft/callback to it? How do I do it?

Comment: @mikefolu Try with localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard

Comment: OK. That means I will not add /microsoft/callback to it

Comment: @mikefolu Yes. Just try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205730/discussion-between-mikefolu-and-tony-ju).

Comment: When I did that, it redirects me to the login page. localhost:8888/peopleedge/login, Why and what do I do?